# Unable to access android.hardware.radio package in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, automotive

[why android studio hide some package?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL8st.png)

I'm trying to use the RadioManager class from the android.hardware.radio package in an Android application, but Android Studio won't allow me to import the package. I've verified that the android.hardware.radio folder exists in my file system and I've tried cleaning the project and invalidating caches, but the issue persists. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: That is not part of the Android SDK. There is no requirement for it to exist on any device. If it does exist, it may be changed by the device manufacturer.

Comment: why i can see it into android sdk directory? (look image) @CommonsWare

Comment: There is a `RadioManager` class in the source code of the framework, at least for some versions of Android. It is not part of the SDK.